# Clear the JavaScript sent to Firebug console

Tags: javascript, firebug

I want to clear the Firebug console of the JavaScript already sent.

Does something like `console.clear()` exist and work?

Comment: I just wonder why didn't you just try it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`console.clear();`

works for me

Comment: What about those of us using chrome?

Comment: @Majid: both Chrome Dev channel (15.0.854.0 dev-m) and Canary build (15.0.859.0 canary) don't have it: TypeError: Object #<Console> has no method 'clear'. When inspecting the console object, clear is not listed. However: just calling clear as a plain function works.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour no it doesn't

Comment: In early 2013, this issue has been fixed! `console.clear()` and `clear()` both do work in current stable version of chrome

Answer (score 9):

If you want to see all the available methods under console:

```
for(var i in console) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: you could also try: `dir(console)` (the methods are listed on __proto__.

Comment: That's `__proto__` when not parsed as Markdown :)

Answer (score 5):

Just a call to the clear function from the console works. However, I can't seem to clear the console from javascript code, but that seems to make sense (you will lose information).

So in Chrome's console, just type:

```
clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can type clear(); in the Firebug command line. I don't think there's a way to do it from a web page though.

Answer (score 1):

_FirebugCommandLine.clear();

Will clear the console

Answer (score 1):

console.clear() is part of the Firebug API. I fixed the documentation page:
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.clear.28.29

jjb